# how create a grid view with dynamic width in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

hi i want to create a grid view in flutter with this parameters:
1 - 3 item in every row
2 - fixed start and end position
3 - the width of every item must set based on the item content
long story short i want to create this :
[image]

i tried [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)  but it set the height of every item based on their content i read the docs but i found nothing.

i try to create the grid view with this code :

```
StaggeredGrid.count(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                crossAxisSpacing: 2 * Responsive().widthConfig,
                mainAxisSpacing: 2 * Responsive().heightConfig,
                children: List.generate(
                  categories.length,
                  (index) => CategoryCard(text: categories[index]),
                ),
              ),
```

and the category card  :

```
class CategoryCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  const CategoryCard({super.key, required this.text});

  @override
  State<CategoryCard> createState() => _CategoryCardState();
}

class _CategoryCardState extends State<CategoryCard> {
  bool isSelected = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isSelected = !isSelected;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: Responsive().heightConfig,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
            2 * Responsive().imageConfig,
          ),
          color: isSelected ? AppTheme.primaryColor : Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(
            color: isSelected ? AppTheme.primaryColor : Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            widget.text,
            style: isSelected
                ? AppTheme.whiteText.labelSmall
                : AppTheme.blackText.labelSmall,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Wrap` Widget it will do like you wanted on the image

e.g.

```
Wrap(
  // also try to add/use runspacing and spacing for each widget/item
  // Also try to use wrap alignment where to start center/start/end
  children:[
    anywidgetWithdifferentWidth(),
    anywidgetWithdifferentWidth(),
    anywidgetWithdifferentWidth(),
  ]
),
```